# Flutter splash screen - The build failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin

Tags: android, flutter

The whole error is like this:

```
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED in 14s
    The build failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetifier to solve the incompatibility.
    Building plugin flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle...
    
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Task 'assembleAarRelease' not found in root project 'flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle'.
    
    * Try:
    Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
    BUILD FAILED in 1s
    
    Exception: The plugin flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle could not be built due to the issue above
```

in the minimum I tried to change the color from white to blue;

`<item android:drawable="@android:color/blue" />`

also tried to created a colors.xml file and changing the above line as :

`<item android:drawable="@color/background" />`

But same error. my sdk compile version is 30, target version is also 30 and minsdk version was 16, but tried to change that to 19 after this error, but no help.

Answer (score 0):

make sure flutter is upgraded or lower version of flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle package